# Gradle compileTestJava fails. It's not finding main classes from console. In Intellij it works fine

Tags: java, gradle

I've been running my build from IntelliJ which uses the gradle wrapper to run tasks.

```
9:38:17 AM: Executing task 'build'...
> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes
> Task :jar
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test
> Task :check
> Task :build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```

The problem starts when I try to do the same from the console:

```
C:\...\TestAPI>gradlew.bat build

> Task :compileTestJava FAILED
C:\...\TestAPI\src\test\java\org\mypackage\AccountServiceTest.java:3: error: package org.mypackage does not exist
import org.mypackage.entities.Account;
```

And many more errors exactly like that. It's not finding any of the classes that are in `src\java\main`.

This is my `build.gradle`.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.mypackage'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.23.4'
}
```

And this is my project structure:

```
.
|-- build.gradle
|-- gradle
|   `-- wrapper
|       |-- gradle-wrapper.jar
|       `-- gradle-wrapper.properties
|-- gradlew
|-- gradlew.bat
|-- settings.gradle
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   |-- java
    |   |   `-- org
    |   |       `-- mypackage
    |   |           `-- entities
    |   |               `-- Account.java
    |   `-- resources
    `-- test
        |-- java
        |   `-- org
        |       `-- mypackage
        |           `-- services
        |               `-- AccountServiceTest.java
        `-- resources
```

Any idea what might be happening.
As I mentioned before the same task executes successfully from IntelliJ.

Comment: Package name is wrong in AccountServiceTest.java as it is clearly visible but in intellij idea has configured the package name.

Comment: What's the project structure and from what location are you running the command?

Comment: Added the project structure, the command is executed form `C:\...\TestAPI` where `build.gradle` is located.

Comment: Sorry, can't show the whole path, but now that you asked,I've noticed it has a space in it. I've moved the whole thing to another directory and it seems to be building fine.